# YouTube XL in WPF WebBrowser?

Tags: wpf, flash, internet-explorer, browser, youtube

I'm trying to create a simple HTPC interface and found YouTube XL (http://youtube.com/xl) which i thought would be cool and easy to add to my program.

I'm using WPF so i simply tried to add a System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser and navigate to that adress.

The problem is that there is no video, everything else around the actual video works fine and other pages(including normal youtube) works fine. Youtube XL also works fine in normal Internet Explorer(8).

Is there anything that differs between IEs and WPFs browser control that might cause this problem?

**Edit:** I am compiling the program for x86, otherwhise flash doesn't work at all. All other web pages i have tried, including normal youtube, works just like normal.

The strangest thing is that it worked once! The first time i tried it i got video, since then there is only black :(

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference.  You might be subject to this bug (and workaround) if you are using an x64 version of Windows:
http://blogs.msdn.com/uberdemo/archive/2009/07/09/circumventing-an-ie-flash-display-issue-in-the-wpf-webbrowser-control-on-x64-machines.aspx

Comment: I ran into that problem before wich took a while to figure out but that's not the problem now, i am running in x86 mode :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the project to compile for x86 processors, since on x64 systems the 64-bit webbrowser is used, which, when i last checked, didn't have a working flash plugin yet. Not sure if there is one now, though.

Comment: I ran into that problem before wich took a while to figure out but that's not the problem now, i am running in x86 mode :(

Answer (score 0):

OP here, accidentally ate my cookies.

Deleting browser history in Internet Explorer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the ie history and cache only resolved the issue as a one time thing only.